# How to show progress towards a directory reaching a certain size

Tags: rsync, file-copy, progress-information

I have a server to which I am copying large amounts of data using `rsync` and I would like to monitor progress on the server, not the client.

I know, for a given source directory on the client how much data is due to be transferred, and I can also find the the current size of the target directory on the server.

Given these two pieces of information, is there any way I can display current progress, for example using `pv`?

Comment: pv works with pipelines, it can hardly be used for this purpose.

Here's a better idea: ssh from your server to your client and then run rsync.

Comment: Not sure if this is allowed, but I cooked myself something up in python for a similar task: https://github.com/panki27/proggy Feed it with a percentage as single argument or with the current count and the total as seperate arguments.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov that's not ideal for me as I don't want to be tied to SSH. I've re-worded the question to make it more general and not specific to `pv`

Comment: @Panki That would be acceptable (see re-worded question) but for me your tool just returns immediately without printing anything, e.g. if I run ./progress.py 30 100

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/219013/showing-total-progress-in-rsync-is-it-possible